# How to ensure that multiple setinterval functions are not intefering

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have created two calculators on a page, the second one calculates properly, however the first one does not. I believe that this is due to my two setinterval functions interfering. How do I get both of these functions to work in conjunction.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("x");
var d = document.getElementById("d");
var xstored = x.getAttribute("data-in");
setInterval(function() {
  if (x == document.activeElement) {
    var temp = x.value;
    if (xstored != temp) {
      xstored = temp;
      x.setAttribute("data-in", temp);
      calculate();
    }
  }
}, 10);

function calculate() {
  d.innerHTML = x.value * .62;
}

var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
var astored = a.getAttribute("data-in");
var c = document.getElementById("c")

setInterval(function() {
  if (a == document.activeElement) {
    var temp = a.value;
    if (astored != temp) {
      astored = temp;
      a.setAttribute("data-in", temp);
      calculate();
    }
  }
}, 50);

function calculate() {
  b.innerHTML = a.value * .62;
  c.innerHTML = Math.round(a.value * .0103);
}

function tisNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;text-align: center;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:50%;background:none;">
        <p style="margin: 0px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 35px;">Lawn Square Footage</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:50%;font-size: 35px;font-weight: bold;background:none">
        <p style="margin: 0px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 35px;">Water Usage</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:50%;">
        <input id="x" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" data-in="" type="text" style="height: 250px;margin-top: 10px;width: 250px;text-align: center;font-size: 100px" />
      </td>
      <td style="width:50%;font-size: 100px;"><span id="d" class="counter"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="width:100%;text-align: center;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:33%;background:none;">
        <p style="margin: 0px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 35px;">Lawn Square Footage</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width:33%;font-size: 35px;font-weight: bold;background:none">
        <p style="margin: 0px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 35px;">Water Usage</p>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:33%;">
        <input id="a" onkeypress="return tisNumberKey(event)" data-in="" type="text" style="height: 250px;margin-top: 10px;width: 250px;text-align: center;font-size: 100px" />
      </td>
      <td style="width:33%;font-size: 100px;"><span id="b" class="counter"></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width:33%;">
        <p style="font-size:50px; font-weight:bold;">Your lawn takes a &nbsp;<span id="c"></span>&nbsp; hour shower
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdyPjE

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 functions with the same name/signature. You have `calculate()` twice you should name one different like `calculate1()`. You are overriding the first `calculate()` function with the second one that is why the second one works but the first one doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

Multiple setInterval functions will **never** interfere with one another, your script runs on a single thread. The functions are queued and will execute one after the other. You don't need to worry about two different functions trying same data at the same time.

Your actual problem appears to be that you have two functions with same name, as pointed out already in another answer.